# How to extract pictures from website which are using a timestamp as name

Tags: images, timestamp

I think I know the answer for this question allready, but just as curious I am, I'll ask it anyways.

I'm running a webshop which products come with a csv file. I can import all the objectsng without any trouble, the only thing is that images and thumbnail locations are not exported with the the database dump. (it's never perfect heh) You might say, do it manually then, that's what I did in the first place, but after 200 products and RSI, I gave it up and looked for a better more efficient way to do this.

I have asked my distributer and I can use their images for my own goals without any having copyright problems.

When I look at the location of the images, the url looks like this:

```
../img/i.php?type=i&file=1250757780.jpg
```

Does anyone have a idea how this problem can be tackled?

Comment: This doesn't tell us the *location* of the images. It just tells us the name of the image file (1250757780.jpg). Obviously, the PHP script called `i.php` knows where to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet would be to change the way the database dumps the info and add in image location.

Answer (score 0):

There are only two possibilities as to what this php script does:

1. It returns the image that it reads itself from the disk,
2. It redirects the browser request.

For the first case, retrieving the images is a lost cause.
However, in the second case you may strike it lucky, as all the images might be stocked in the same directory.

To find out if you're in the second case, when some image is finally displayed, right-click on it and regard its Properties. If you now see a fixed location in the Location field, then you're in luck.

Comment: Right clicking and showing properties still will most likely show the '../img/i.php?type=i&file=1250757780.jpg' address.

Comment: it looks indeed like that

Comment: Then it's indeed a lost cause.